# SQL : SELECT SUM WHERE CONDITION

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, where-clause

I've got some troubles about SQL request :
I have a table like this [table data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKY6r.png)

I would like to create a view from this table to get :

Time_A : **SUM** of a column (total_time_taken) **WHERE** column (is_radiant)=**1**

Time_B : **SUM** of the same column (total_time_taken) **WHERE** column (is_radiant)=**0**

Time_AB : **SUM** of the column (total_time_taken) **WHERE** column (is_radiant)=**0** OR (is_radiant)=**1**

```
SELECT 
    SUM(`matchpickban_radiant`.`total_time_taken`) AS `draft_time_radiant`,
    SUM(`matchpickban_dire`.`total_time_taken`) AS `draft_time_radiant`
FROM
    (`matchpickban` AS `matchpickban_radiant`
    JOIN `matchpickban` AS `matchpickban_dire` ON ((`matchpickban_dire`.`idmatchpickban` = `matchpickban_radiant`.`idmatchpickban`)))
WHERE
    `matchpickban_radiant`.`is_radiant` = 1
    AND `matchpickban_dire`.`is_radiant` = 0
```

Actually I can run this request without syntax error but the result is NULL cause no data can be equal to 0 AND equal to 1 in the same time, obviously...

Also, I don't know if it's possible to make a JOIN the table to itself as I did (matchpickban JOIN matchpickban).

If syntax is correct I need to place my WHERE CONDITION away but don't know how, is it possible to replace it with 2 **IF** statement (IF is_radiant=0 SUM(...))

Thx for reading and helping me about this issue I got !
If you need more info about table or request I will give you all you need !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a self-join or complex logic, you can just use conditional aggregation, which consists in using conditional expression *within* aggregate functions.

In MySQL, you could go:

```
select 
    sum(is_radiant * total_time_taken) time_a,
    sum((1 - is_radiant) * total_time_taken) time_b,
    sum(total_time_taken) time_ab
from matchpickban
where is_radiant in (0, 1)
```

This works because `is_radiant` is made of  0`/1` values only - so this simplifies the logic. A more canonical way to phrase the conditional sums would be:

```
sum(case when is_radiant = 1 then total_time_taken else 0 end) time_a,
sum(case when is_radiant = 0 then total_time_taken else 0 end) time_b,
```

Comment: Probably useful to also show an IIF/CASE version, and explain why your shortcut/simplification is probably fine.

Comment: @MatBailie: yes. I expanded my answer a little.

Comment: This 2 solutions worked fine for me ! Thx for the fast reply, and the explanations, I learned something !